# Saving an array to file with nodejs and post method

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, fs

I am using ejs and nodejs.
Trying to post an array to a file. I can visualize and get the array in ejs file so it is ok to show on the page  but when I try to save in a file, it return [object Object] in file. But I can see the values in array.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');

const todos = [];
const file = 'ToDox.txt'
// /admin/add-product => GET
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index', { pageTitle: 'Add ToDo Page'});
});

// /admin/add-product => POST
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  todos.push({ title: req.body.title, description: req.body.description});
  res.redirect('/todos');
  console.log(todos);
  fs.writeFile(file, todos, (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('Successfuly written to the file!');
  })
});

exports.routes = router;
exports.todos = todos;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `JSON.stringify` to convert in string

```
fs.writeFile('todo.txt', JSON.stringify(todos), (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log('Successfuly written to the file!');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing to a file using fs you are passing your todos which is an Array of Object. This is why you see *[object Object]*. Try to send the array to the function *JSON.stringify(todos)* and use the output which will be a string.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried destructuring the array somehow? I believe that the issue you're having is related to the data type you're passing into the fs.writeFile(). The node.js documentation says that the data parameter can be in the form of a String, Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView.

For more information, https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback